# Concurrency issue on single thread?

Tags: java, android, concurrency, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a piece of code that adds a second entry to an ArrayList, and another that fetches the update. This works most of the time, but every once in a while I get an IndexOutOfBOundsException, indicating the index hasn't been updated with the second value. The test is easy, I just press the same button a bunch of times, and after an arbitrary number of presses, the program crashes.

The following two parts, contained in a Fragment, are called after each other:

This adds an item to the arraylist:

```
if ( mTaskPaused == false ) {
    mTask.timeStamp ();
}
```

And this, called directly after, gets the second (sometimes non-existing) item from the arraylist:

```
LocalDateTime end = mTask.getTimestamps ().get ( 1 );
```

What on earth is happening here?

Comment: the code that you posted is not enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Besides, if there is only a single thread involved (as the Question title implies!!) then this is not a concurrency issue.

Comment: Indeed, there is only a single thread. Or at least, *I'm* not creating any other threads. That's why the inconsistent behavior puzzles me.

Comment: What type is `mTask`? Its name suggests it might execute in its own thread...

Comment: Captain Hindsight - if there is only one thread, this it is a "bug" ... not a "concurrency issue".  A "concurrency issue on a single thread" is a contradiction in terms.  Like a "unicycle with two wheels".

Comment: @StephenC : Like this one ? --> http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_7gYNb3GSh4M/SItDmRShSQI/AAAAAAAAFLA/7JE2lNAvBzc/s400/learn_2wheel.jpg ^_^

Comment: @MrSMAK - Why did you link to a picture of a tricycle with a missing front wheel?  :-)

Comment: @StephenC To prove your "unicycle with two wheels" sentence.
P.S: Pun intended :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mTask.getTimestamps().count()>=1)
{
LocalDateTime end = mTask.getTimestamps ().get (1);
}
else
{
    //Do the handling here for Arrays with only single entry.
}
```

I hope this helps. For proper Solution, you need to post the complete code.